# Formatting cells through a custom formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to implement a custom functionality in a worksheet so that it would be possible to enter a number in a cell and the cell color would be changed to the RGB value of that number. Is it possible to do this with a custom formula? Say, the formula in the cell would look like this `=SHOWCOLOR(123456)` and VB function would look like this:

```
Function ShowColor(cv As Integer)
ActiveCell.Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .color = cv
    End With
End Function
```

I tried this approach, but getting the 'wrong type data value' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can only return a value, but the event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = Target.Value
End Sub
```

will get you the desired functionality.